Type hinting a python descriptor implementing read-only instance attributes after initialisation
I have a couple of data structure classes that are intended to have public read-only attributes. I cannot use dataclasses or namedtuples as I need the ability to define args, kwargs in the child classes inheriting these classes.
One way I can set this up is simply having read-only properties but at some point, my data structure can have more than 20 attributes and writing a property for each one of them feels cumbersome.
I think the best solution for me would be to implement a descriptor and I have an implementation which works but mypy seems to be struggling with it:
from typing import  Type, TypeVar, Generic

_Object = TypeVar("_Object")
_Value = TypeVar("_Value")


class ReadOnlyAttribute(Generic[_Value]):
    def __set_name__(self, owner: Type[_Object], name: str) -> None:
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = f"_{name}"

    def __get__(self, instance: _Object, owner: Type[_Object]) -> _Value:
        return getattr(instance, self.private_name)

    def __set__(self, instance: _Object, value: _Value) -> None:
        if hasattr(instance, self.private_name):
            raise AttributeError(
                f"Cannot set read-only attribute '{self.public_name}' of '{instance}'"
            )

        setattr(instance, self.private_name, value)


class Test:
    #  error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "ReadOnlyAttribute[Never]", variable has type "str")  [assignment]
    foo: str = ReadOnlyAttribute()

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "foooooo"

#  Revealed type is "builtins.str"
reveal_type(Test().foo)

It is able to infer the type correctly but is giving an error about incompatible types in assignment. I think it's because I am type-hinting self.foo as a str but assigning an instance of ReadOnlyAttribute?
However, without doing this and using Generic, reveal_type does not perform as expected and returns Never.

foo: str = ReadOnlyAttribute() - no, forgo the str annotation and do this instead: foo = ReadOnlyAttribute[str](). But IMO a bigger usability issue is that you're not statically typing __set__ to warn users of its read-only nature. I would do def __set__(self, instance: typing_extensions.Never, value: <anything>) -> None: ...  instead.

To add to previous comment, _Object typevar is used incorrectly in your snippet - it isn't bound to the class (probably good for usability) and only occurs in signatures of __set__ and __set_name__ once. I'd just use plain Any there. You could make ReadOnlyAttribute generic in this var, but that will add more verbosity for little to no benefit.

Never isn't correct, because __set__ can (and will) be called once without raising. I think we'd need linear types to assert statically that __set__ should only be called once.

You could implement these using properties, simply by allowing Test.__init__ initialize the underlying attribute directly. Will your __set__ actually apply any validation or logic to the value before initialization of the private attribute?

@dROOOze, __set__ will be called once without raising when the value of the public attribute is set in the __init__ as @chepner pointed out. However, even if I had to typehint as a never returning function, isn't def __set__(self, instance: _Object, value: <anything>):  -> Never: ... better?

@chepner The correctness of the public interface comes first - and to achieve something like a read-only attribute, statically typing __set__ with arguments that a user is never be able to provide is the only way to do this, AFAIK. How someone actually sets the instance variables in the object initialisation phase is an implementation detail; e.g. using setattr would avoid any spurious warnings associated with Never.

I don't know what type-checker you're using, but the support of -> Never for descriptors in my experience is not great. mypy, for example, doesn't do anything. Besides, even if a warning did show up, that doesn't actually solve the problem - you'd still get the warning inside __init__ as you do with Never in an argument.

@chepner, I am not able to follow your comment over the use of _Object?  The descriptor can be used in any class and the owner as well as the instance will change depending on what class is calling it.  instance: _Object, owner: Type[_Object] is quite explicit in conveying the idea that the owner is the class of the instance as supposed to instance: Any, owner: Type[Any] which implies that there could be disparity between the owner class and instance object? Also, can you explain more on what you mean by it is not bound to a class?

@chepner, right now, the only reason I am using descriptors is for the read-only behavior. The reason I am not writing properties is simply because there are quite a few attributes and I wanted to find an easier way of defining them compared to writing a property for each.

@dROOOze, forgive me if what I wrote was not technically correct as I only discovered Never when I saw this error. I have never used it in the past. My question was more on the idea of it rather than how I declare it. With a quick google search, I got the idea that Never is intended to be used for type-hinting things that "never" return. In that case, (...) -> Never is what it should be as opposed to (..., instance: Never) -> None? I am confused over what your type-hints convey :)

Please see the Python docs on typing.Never: typing.Never can be used...to define a function that should never be called, as there are no valid arguments, ....

See this answer regarding binding typevars. For __get__ your typing is sound: there is a dependency between two params and you declare it using a typevar. For __set__, however, you use this type variable only once in params: that is equivalent to just using its upper bound directly except for few variance-related cases. To bind _Object to the class, you'd need to use Generic[_Object] as its base. To bind _Object to a func/method, you need to include it at least twice.

@dROOOze  "The correctness of the public interface comes first - and to achieve something like a read-only attribute, statically typing set with arguments that a user is never be able to provide is the only way to do this, AFAIK." Which is why I say Never is incorrect, because the user does provide an argument, once. self.foo = "foooooo" calls the __set__ method. It's only after this first call to __set__ that you want to prohibit further calls. Statically, you can't distinguish between "first call" and "subsequent calls".

@chepner I actually agree with @dROOOze here: it's "I need to type-ignore one call" vs "I want to be warned that this is read-only every other time". Depending on the test coverage and overall development practices, it might be feasible to say "yes, just type-ignore assignments in __init__, but never do that outside of it". Since you can't achieve both at the same time, you need to choose something, and both options are sound.

Here's a comparison of those (together with what I said about _Object): https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=bae841f445f9d4abd82267ceb853e29a The Never option is good to maintain a public interface of containing class correct: it does statically prevent assignments to those read-only properties.

Then you have to tell the type checker to ignore self.foo = "foooooo". I would still just define a getter-only property; foo = property(lambda self: self._foo) is not significantly more work than foo = SomeCustomDescriptor().
